# Как правильно реализовать итератор для бинарного дерева?

Tags: алгоритм, бинарное-дерево, итераторы

Есть простое бинарное дерево, для него нужно реализовать итератор.
Вопрос в том, какие функции он должен выполнять? Бинарное дерево не является линейной структурой данных, тогда что должены возвращать методы begin и end? Что делать в случае, когда через итератор пользователь пытается изменить данныу(получается, дерево должно удалить элемент и сгенерировать новый), или в итераторе бинарного дерева эта функция должна отсутствовать? Что допустимо, а что нет ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Обычно итератор используется лишь для перебора значений, так что никакой замены там не должно быть.

Я немного работал с деревьями, в том числе и с бинарными. Если правильно понимаю, то у Вас есть как бы пары Ключ-Значение, где Ключ - целое число.

Ну так вот, если вспомнить итераторы Java, Вам нужно реализовать два метода:

- hasNext(): bool - говорит о наличии следующего элемента
- next(): any - возвращает элемент и смещает указатель.

И вот тут возникают некоторые сложности. Бинарное дерево может содержать несколько элементов доступных по ключам от 0 до 100, а может содержать первый элемент, доступный по ключу 2000000000. В таком случае итерировать ключи и проверять есть ли по ним что-то - медленно.

В самом дереве определите метод getNextKey (key), который бы просто рекурсивно возвращал следующий по возрастанию (убыванию) доступный ключ после переданного. Аргументу key не обязательно указывать на элемент, он лишь "отправная точка"

Сам же итератор будет запрашивать элементы и запоминать следующий ключ. Как-то так